# Java ArrayList first item collision doesn't work, but without it works

Tags: java, arraylist, libgdx, collision-detection, rectangles

I am creating an ArrayList items of Rectangles:

```
private ArrayList<Rectangle> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

I use the `ArrayList` in my `update` method.

```
@Override
public void update(float delta) {

    items.add(new Rectangle(GameWorld.obstacle1.getX() - GameRenderer.generator2.getValue2(),
                GameWorld.obstacle1.getY() + GameRenderer.generator2.getValue1() , 5, 5));

        if (Intersector.overlaps(GameWorld.wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), items.get(0))) {                
            Gdx.app.exit();             
        }    
}
```

The collision with the item **does not work**, because the program doesn't close when it hits the item.

But when I do it like this, it works perfectly fine:

```
private Rectangle doublepoints;

doublepoints = new Rectangle(GameWorld.obstacle1.getX() - GameRenderer.generator2.getValue2(),
                GameWorld.obstacle1.getY() + GameRenderer.generator2.getValue1() , 5, 5);

@Override
public void update(float delta) {

        if (Intersector.overlaps(GameWorld.wizard.getBoundingRectangle(), doublepoints)) {                
            Gdx.app.exit();             
        }    
}
```

I don't understand why the latter works, but I'd really like to do it with the `ArrayList`. Can someone tell me why?

Breakpoint (ArrayList):

[image]

Breakpoint (normal):

[image]

Comment: are you sure that what you have added is the first item ? run it with debugger and see if there is any other object being added before `update(float delta)` is being called

Comment: @mkhj Does not seem to be the case. I checked with a debugger and breaking points. Edited post with link

Comment: Maybe the issue is with `GameWorld.wizard.getBoundingRectangle()` then? Have you verified it returns the same value in both cases?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, as a proof I just edited the original post with 2 images

Comment: In the example where you use a Rectangle instead of the List, you assign the rectangle OUTSIDE the scope of the update method. Is this a mistake or by design? 

As a sign note - a best practice is to use the List interface as the type of the items attribute, instead of the concrete ArrayList. The rationale being - you can then easily change the implementation type of the items  List whenever you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the rest of your code but wouldnt below code add a rectangle in each render update? (60 a second)

```
public void update(float delta) {

items.add(new Rectangle(GameWorld.obstacle1.getX() - GameRenderer.generator2.getValue2(),
            GameWorld.obstacle1.getY() + GameRenderer.generator2.getValue1() , 5, 5));}
```

Problem might be related to this issue.

Use:

```
System.out.println(items.size());
```

to check for it.